# Cron job does not start at hh:10

Tags: cron

```
*/10 * * * *
```

This should run the job (PHP script) every 10 minutes, but it does not ran at hh:10... The PHP script writing data to a MySQL database which should be done every 10 minutes

e.g.

- 2021-12-29 21:20:08
- 2021-12-29 21:00:08
- 2021-12-29 20:50:07
- 2021-12-29 20:40:12
- 2021-12-29 20:30:05
- 2021-12-29 20:20:13
- 2021-12-29 20:00:04
- 2021-12-29 19:50:14
- 2021-12-29 19:40:09
- 2021-12-29 19:30:06
- 2021-12-29 19:20:04
- 2021-12-29 19:00:07
- 2021-12-29 18:50:05

My webhoster is "easyname GmbH" (easyname Ltd.) and they are using **CloudPit v7.9.3**.

- PHP Version 7.0.33
- System    Linux web1.wh20.easyname.systems 3.10.0-962.3.2.lve1.5.60.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jul 23 07:07:00 EDT 2021 x86_64
- Build Date    Dec 7 2018 12:53:55

I tried it with "execute PHP script" which worked for some month (but also not executed hh:10) but on 20th of December it stopped working at all. Today (29th, December) changed it to URL (providing the URL to my PHP) script which is working again, but also not running at hh:10

Exists there a known issue with the used version or provider? The support staff didn't find the problem...

Answer (score 3):

based on [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/#*/10_*_*_*_*), your cron job should be running every 10 minutes
I would guess that the user context that it is running in might be the issue here, not the cron setting